# Html data attribute array of hash format

Tags: html, coding-style, custom-data-attribute

Which format do you recommand for passing an array of hash in a Html data attribute.
For instance:

```
<button data-products="[{
              id='1',
              name='A Product Name',
              value='1000',
             },{
              id='2',
              name='A Second Product Name',
              value='2000',
             }]">
```

I don't find any convention for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON format, example with ruby and html languages:

```
<% result = {a: 'a', b: 'b'} %>
<button data-example="<%= result.to_json %>">Lorem</button>
```

Inside your javascript, use `JSON.parse()`.